# make vector of PlainTextDocuments

Tags: r, tm

I have this closure, which is meant to parse one `PlainTextDocument` into several child `PlainTextDocument`s while transferring and augmenting the metadata:

```
segment_doc <- function(doc) {
    txt = paste0(doc, collapse=' ')
    au <- meta(doc, tag='Author');
    desc <- meta(doc, tag='description');
    ori <- meta(doc, tag='origin');
    locmeta <- attr(doc,'LocalMetaData');

    function(df){
        dfrows <- nrow(df);
        v<-rep(NA,dfrows);
        for(i in 1:dfrows) {
            a <- df[i,'after'];
            b <- df[i, 'before'];
            m <- df[i, 'meta'];

            sec <-PlainTextDocument(mkmeta(b, a, txt), author= au, description=desc, origin=ori, heading = m, localmetadata= locmeta) 
            #verified using debug that sec is a 'PlainTextDocument' with the expected text and metadata 
            v[i]=sec;

        }
        v #should be a vector of PlainTextDocuments, BUT it is vector of character vectors. WHY??

    }
}
```

which I can use as follows:

```
# mycorpus is a Corpus object containing PlainTextDocuments
# sections is a data.frame with 3 columns of type character named 'before', 'after' and 'meta' and 6 rows

sectioner <- segment_doc(mycorpus[[1]]); 
ptv <- sectioner(sections); #expect a vector of 6 PlainTextDocuments

class(ptv);
[1] "character" 
length(ptv);
[1] 6
```

### Questions

- Why is `sec` transformed from a `PlainTextDocument` object to a character vector when placed in a vector?
- How can I make `sectioner` return a `Corpus` object? (a vector of `PlainTextDocument`s would also be fine).

I've read the documentation on `tm`. Yes, all of it. This shouldn't be so hard. Is there a different approach I should be using?

Comment: The reason why you get a character vector returned is, that you initialize `v` as a atomic vector which cannot carry complex objects. Instead, the objects which are put in the vector are coerced to a common atomic data type (here a character). You could initialize `v` as list with `v <- vector( length = dfrows, mode= 'list' )`.

Comment: @Beasterfield: that helps a lot. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `sectioner` returns a character vector is because you initialize `v` as a atomic vector which cannot carry complex objects. Instead, the objects which are put in the vector are coerced to a common atomic data type (here a character). You could initialize v as list with

```
v <- vector( length = dfrows, mode= 'list' ).
```